# python while loop break

Tags: python

I am trying to make an on/off switch for my program:
(see after the `###` for what I'm talking about)

```
while 1:
    str = raw_input("insert your word: ")
    n = input("insert your scalar: ")
    def string_times(str, n):
        return n * str
    print string_times(str, n)

    ###
    def switch(on,off):
        raw_input("On or off? ")
        if switch == "on":
            continue
        if switch == "off":
            break
    switch(on,off)
```

I get a continue not in loop error.  Basically, I want to create an on or off switch after the program runs once.  What do I fix?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use `break` and `continue` in a nested function. Use the return value of the function instead:

```
def switch():
    resp = raw_input("On or off? ")
    return resp == "on":

while True:
    # other code

    if not switch():
        break
```

Note that there is little point in defining your functions in the loop. Define them before the loop, as creating the function object takes some performance (albeit a small amount).

The `switch()` function needs no arguments (you didn't use them at all), and the `continue` is also not needed. If you didn't break out of the loop, it'll just continue from the top when you reach the end.

You only need `continue` if you want the loop to start at the top again *skipping the rest of the code* in the loop:

```
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    print count
    if loop % 2 == 0:
        continue

    print 'We did not continue and came here instead.'

    if count >= 3:
        break

    print 'We did not break out of the loop.'
```